QGIS - distance from point to point on a specific bearing e.g. north (0 degrees)
I am using QGIS and have a layer that is the country centroids, tectonic plate boundaries in both line and point form. This is what I have achieved so far - shortest distance from centroid to tectonic plate boundary 
What I am trying to do is measure the distance from the centroid of each country, to their nearest tectonic plate boundary for a specific bearing or cardinal directions. ie the closest tectonic plate boundary north of the centre of country x. - I want to complete it for all countries of the world. example using india's centroid in yellow to the tectonic boundaries in black 
I have managed to ascertain the distance from the centre of the country to the closest tectonic plate boundary. However for my research I really need it to be bearing base, as I eventually would want to extrapolate it to N, S, W, E and potentially more cardinal directions.
Do you know how to achieve something like this, or would be able to help.
let me know if you have any questions!
